# Bat file open chrome in app mode with focus

Tags: google-chrome, batch-file, focus, hta

I'm trying to make a HTA application that works like a program launcher..

But I have some problems with apps, that opens below my HTA app..

Right now i'm trying to open a webpage in chrome with app mode. But chrome starts below my hta..

The code I use to open the webage in chrome app mode:

```
Start "" "%ProgramFiles(x86)%\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" chrome --app=https://www.google.com/
```

I have not been able to find a solution that I can get to work.. I Have no prior experience with batch programming etc.

Edit:
Hta app i'm making is used to lock down some gaming commputers in a after school club. I have done so the user don't have access to the desktop.. I have disabled ALT+F4 etc. in the application so i can't be closed..

But now they want to play web games like plix.io, so I made the batch script below to launch the game and make it possible to join a team game without browser access with adress bar visible.

this is my bat file

```
@echo off

rem not really necessary for this part
title Splix.io Launcher
color 0f
mode con: cols=80 lines=15
rem below is necessary
cls
goto main
@echo off

:main
Echo .
Echo                                Splix.io Launcher
Echo  ÉÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍ»
Echo  º                                                                            º
Echo  º 1 Start Splix      Start singpleplayer eller host en team server           º
Echo  º                                                                            º
Echo  º 2 Join Team spil   Deltag i et team spil                                   º
Echo  º                                                                            º
Echo  º 3 EXIT             Luk Splix.io Launcher                                   º
Echo  º                                                                            º
Echo  ÈÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍ¼
Echo .
Choice /C 123 /M "Vil du starte singleplayer eller join et team spil:"
If Errorlevel 3 Goto 3
If Errorlevel 2 Goto team
If Errorlevel 1 Goto single

:single
Start "" "%ProgramFiles(x86)%\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" chrome --app=https://www.splix.io/
echo Starter Splix.io
exit

:team
cls
color 0f
set str=error
echo Skriv de sidste 5 tegn fra Splix team adressen på hjemmesiden
echo.
set /p str=Splix.io/#team- 
set len=0
goto sl

:sl
call set this=%%str:~%len%%%
if not "%this%" == "" (set /a len+=1
goto :sl)
cls
if not "%len%" == "5" (echo Fejl, Du skal skrive de sidste 5 tegn i Splix team adressen
color 4f
pause >nul
cls
goto team)
Start "" "%ProgramFiles(x86)%\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" chrome --app=https://www.splix.io/#team-%str%
echo Starter Splix.io Team spil
exit

:3
cls
exit
```

I don't knows if the problem is the batch script or the code i use in the HTA to enable me to open programs from the hta:

```
function runApp(which) {
WshShell = new ActiveXObject("WScript.Shell");
WshShell.Run (which,1,true);
}
```

Can anyone tell me how I focus on the Chrome app after I open it?

Comment: Well, batch is probably the worst choice for controlling GUI applications as it is simply not made for that...

Comment: Okay, I edited the topic and added some more info..

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this HTA file can help you :

```
<html>
<head>
<HTA:APPLICATION
APPLICATIONNAME="Open link with chrome browser"
BORDER="THIN"
BORDERSTYLE="NORMAL"
ICON="Explorer.exe"
INNERBORDER="NO"
MAXIMIZEBUTTON="NO"
MINIMIZEBUTTON="NO"
SCROLL="NO"
SELECTION="NO"
SINGLEINSTANCE="YES"/>
<META HTTP-EQUIV="MSThemeCompatible" CONTENT="YES">
<title>Open link with chrome browser</title>
<SCRIPT LANGUAGE="VBScript">
'************************************************************************************
Option Explicit
 Function Executer(StrCmd)
 Dim ws,MyCmd,Resultat
 Set ws = CreateObject("wscript.Shell")
 MyCmd = "CMD /C " & StrCmd & " "
 Resultat = ws.run(MyCmd,0,True)
 Executer = Resultat
End Function
'************************************************************************************
Sub window_onload()
 CenterWindow 400,320
End Sub
'************************************************************************************
Sub CenterWindow(x,y)
 Dim iLeft,itop
 window.resizeTo x,y
 iLeft = window.screen.availWidth/2 - x/2
 itop = window.screen.availHeight/2 - y/2
 window.moveTo ileft,itop
End Sub
'************************************************************************************
</script>
</head>
<p>Links :</p>
<ol>
<li><a href="#" onClick="Call Executer('Start chrome.exe www.google.com chrome --app=https://www.google.com/')">Link Google</a></li>
<li><a href="#" onClick="Call Executer('Start chrome.exe https://stackoverflow.com chrome --app=https://stackoverflow.com/')">Link Stackoverflow with Chrome.exe</a></li>
<li><a href="#" onClick="Call Executer('Start chrome.exe www.yahoo.fr chrome --app=www.yahoo.fr/')">Link Yahoo with Chrome.exe</a></li>
<li><a href="#" onClick="Call Executer('Start chrome.exe www.autoitscript.fr chrome --app=www.autoitscript.fr/')">Link Autoitscript.fr (Français) with Chrome.exe</a></li>
<li><a href="#" onClick="Call Executer('Start chrome.exe www.autoitscript.com chrome --app=www.autoitscript.com/')">Link autoitscript.com (Anglais) with Chrome.exe</a></li>
</ol>
<BODY text=white bgcolor="DarkOrange" TOPMARGIN="1" LEFTMARGIN="1">
 <center><button onclick="Call Executer('Start chrome.exe www.google.com chrome --app=https://www.google.com/')">Open Google Link </button></center>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply.. It do look like a better way to open programs.. However I have some problems with the script not working, when my HTA uses content="IE=9" meta tag.. I need it to work with IE=9 as everything else breaks without it..

Comment: I did some testing with your script and it looks like Chrome, don't have the problems with the chrome window opens behind my fullscreen HTA when I launch Chrome using your HTA script. So I will be awesome if I could scrap the bat stuff and use something like that. However I still need the user input, that adds it to the url.. Just like my batch file. After some googling i have not found any easy scripts or anything that could help me build this.. Like I've mention I have not worked with HTA before and very little with batch files. So I could really use a simple example of how this works.